# Question about scanf() with lf specifier and printf() with lf specifier?

Tags: c, printf, scanf

I am learning C and I have the following code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  double x;
  printf("x = ");
  scanf("%ld", &x);
  printf("x = %lf\n", x);

  system("PAUSE");  
  return 0;
}
```

(I am using Dev C4.9, Windows XP SP3)

When I run the above program and entered 5.3; the program printed `x = 0.000000`

Can anyone explain why is that, please?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `%ld` format string means that it's expecting to read in a `long signed int`, but you're passing it instead a `double`.  You should instead use the `%lf` format specifier to say that you want a `double`.

Note that for `scanf`, the `l` is required for `double`s (and is required to be absent for `float`s), whereas for `printf`, the `l` in `%lf` has no effect: both `%f` and `%lf` have the same output for both `float`s and `double`s, due to default argument promotion.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I know I have added the wrong specifier. But I want to know how scanf() works so that it produced the wrong result. Could you please elaborate on that?

Comment: @ipkiss: As `scanf` reads the format string, it sees `%ld`, which says to it "the next parameter passed in to me must be a `long int*`.  I'm going to parse the string as a `long int` and store the parsed value in the pointer-to location."  As a result, it parses the number "5" and stores that into the 4 bytes at the beginning of your `double` variable.  When you use `%ld`, it instead parses the string as a `double` and stores the value as a `double` in the pointed-to location, which is what you want.

Comment: @Adam Rosenfield: so, I thought it would have printed out: 5.00000 rather 0.000000. Am I thinking wrong?

Comment: @ipkiss doubles and longs are both stored as sequences of bytes in memory, but they have different lengths and representations. Storing a long into part of the memory used for a double has undefined consequences -- you can't count on it resulting in any particular double or even a valid double at all.

Comment: @Adam you meant "When you use %lf", not "... %ld" in your comment.

Answer (score 0):

for your `scanf`  ld:

```
same as "%d" except argument is "long" integer. Since "long"
is the same as "int" on GCOS8,this is the same as "%d". However, the compiler 
will warn you if you specify "%ld" but pass a normal "int", or specify "%d" but 
pass a "long".
```

for your `printf` lf:

```
same as "%f" except argument is "long double". 
Since "long double" is the same as "double" on GCOS8, this is the same as "%f".
```

[read this.](http://www.thinkage.ca/english/gcos/expl/c/lib/printf.html)

Answer (score 0):

Be consistent with the data with scanf and printf.
Plus for %lf(double), %f(float), %lld(long long int) i've experienced problem in windows. It's not well implemented in windows (msvcrt.dll if you ask).

Answer (score -1):

It's better to use `gets()` and then try to parse and convert the entered string to the desired type.

Because everything is input initially as a string and it's easier to handle bad input.

scanf requires the input to be perfect and that doesn't always happen when humans are keying in data.

Comment: Woah! Never *ever* use `gets`. **EVER!**

Comment: Thats bad for the security and for the speed. FYI http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_standard_library#Criticism

Comment: Are you kidding me?  It is *never* better to use `gets()` than *anything*!

Comment: Aside from the fact that `gets` creates a security hole waiting to be exploited, and that your "answer" does not in any way address the question at hand, your comment makes no sense. If the input is invalid, then it's invalid, and it doesn't matter whether you read a line (e.g., via `fgets`) and then parse it (e.g., via `sscanf`), or read the input directly via `scanf`. It is generally easier to do the former when dealing with line-oriented input, but that's a different matter.