# How to evaluate seriers of numbers

Tags: c

I have a string like `-1,1.51,-2.525,3.456...` etc values.

I need to convert this each value(`string`) to `float` and add all the values to produce result.

Again I need to  convert resulted float to string with two number after decimal point.

Example : `-1+1.51-2.525+3.456 = 1.44.`

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Use `strtok`, `strtod` and `printf`.

Comment: Show the code for what you've tried.

Comment: atoi("2.5") i used this function to conver it to integer but not working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look up the `strtof()` function, it's perfect for doing things like this. Note that it parses a floating-point number, and also returns a pointer to the first character *not* considered part of the number.

Comment: The OP said `float`, but `strtod` is for `double`. I think you mean `strtof`.

Comment: @ams Good point. I typically use `strtod()` as the default choice and just drop the precision when storing the values, but that's of course less clear. Edited, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The following code will help you to split your string with `sscanf()` function

To display float with 2 numbers after decimal point use `"%.2f"`

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>

char str[256]="-1,1.51,-2.525,3.456";

int main()
{
    float x, sum=0; int g;
    while (g=sscanf(str,"%f,%s",&x,str))
    {

        printf("x=%f\r\n",x);
        sum+=x;
        if (g==1) break;
    }
    printf(" the sum is %.2f\r\n",sum);
}
```

**Build and execution:**

```
linux$ gcc -o test test.c -lpthread
linux$ ./test
x=-1.000000
x=1.510000
x=-2.525000
x=3.456000
 the sum is 1.44
```

Comment: Are you sure about the "recursive" use of `str` as both the source and destination arguments of `sscanf()`?

Comment: @unwind if the usage of recursive str buffer cause a proble (but we have to check this with the standard) we can use another buffer

Comment: code updtaed to support displaying float with 2 number after the decimal point

Comment: @JanHudec `%lf` is for double. The `%f` could be used for floats: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5215303/question-about-scanf-with-lf-specifier-and-printf-with-lf-specifier

Comment: @MohamedKALLEL: Yes, you are right; printf and scanf differ here.

Comment: There's really no need to copy the whole string back into `str` again (and yes, that does look like undefined behaviour anyway). Instead, use `%n` to return the offset to the next number, and then pass `&str[n]` the next time around the loop.